# Firebase ,Display post with The next path "self.dataBaseRef.child("Posts").child(uid).childByAutoId()"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have to display post(s) with firebase, the post is on the path:

```
self.dataBaseRef.child("Posts").child(uid).childByAutoId()
```

Where

```
"uid" = FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.uid

dataBaseRef = FIRDatabaseReference! {
    return FIRDatabase.database().reference()
}
```

The publication of the post on Firebase works with success, but I can't get to this path because I can not declare the `uid` because  is specific to each user. How?

Comment: If my answer helped, mark it pls. To let others know, that it's answer

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
let dataBaseRef = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "Posts")

dataBaseRef.observe(.value, with: { snapshot in
        for item in snapshot.children {
            let childSnap = item as! FIRDataSnapshot // do something you wants to
            // childSnap contains item in Posts. So in cycle you will catch
            // every post child node. From here you can get uid's 
            // and make a new observer
        }
})
```

Hope it helps